# Ind-completion of a 2-category

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, higher-category-theory, 2-categories

If $\mathcal{C}$ is a category, there is a well known construction called [the Ind-completion of $\mathcal{C}$](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/ind-object), indicated by $\text{Ind}(\mathcal{C})$. This can be equivalently defined in several ways: for example, $\text{Ind}(\mathcal{C})$ may be seen as the full subcategory of $[\mathcal{C}^{op}, \mathbf{Set}]$ whose objects are those presheaves which are isomorphic to filtered colimits of representables. This construction has a universal property: namely, each functor $\mathcal{C}\rightarrow\mathcal{D}$, with $\mathcal{D}$ a category with filtered colimits, factors uniquely through the inclusion $\mathcal{C}\hookrightarrow\text{Ind}(\mathcal{C})$.

Now let $\mathcal{C}$ be a 2-category, and consider the 2-category of pseudofunctors $F:\mathcal{C}^{op}\rightarrow\mathbf{Cat}$ which are isomorphic to filtered pseudocolimits of representables, with the usual pseudonatural transformations and modifications.

My question is: has this 2-category ever been studied? Does it have a universal property similar to the one of the Ind-completion of a category?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find discussion of this in [Lack's 2-categories companion](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4419-1524-5_4). The original reference in a more general context is Kelly's [Structures defined by finite limits in the enriched context](https://eudml.org/doc/urn:eudml:doc:91287). See more discussion in Lack and Rosicky's [Notions of Lawvere Theory](https://doi.org/10.1007/s10485-009-9215-2).

The theory is a bit more delicate because often one really wants to work up to 2-equivalence, but the most "automatic" way to develop the theory views 2-categories as categories enriched in $Cat$, so the natural notion of equivalence is stricter.